# Splitting a string value inside list<>

Tags: c#, list, split

I have a list contained within a dictionary that contains the follwing values

```
value a
value b
value c
value 1, value 2, value3
value d
```

the end result I would like is

```
value a
value b
value c
value 1
value 2
value 3
value d
```

problem is iterating through the dictionary and trying to change the collection will not work as I am trying to modify it while looping through it

```
string[] ar;
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            if (kvp.Key == "STAR-016")
            {
                foreach (var v in kvp.Value)
                {
                    if (v.Contains(','))
                    {
                        ar = v.Split(',');
                        foreach (var a in ar)
                        {
                            kvp.Value.Add(a);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

how can i get the desired result?

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve? What's the end result?

Comment: did you try creating anothet list and adding every result to that one?

Comment: Is "value 1, value 2, value 3" a string literal then?

Comment: I think the fact that this is all in a dictionary is excessive information. This issue appears to be that the OP is trying to modify the contents of the `List<string>` within a foreach-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is just an example and you actually want this not only for a key `STAR-016` but for all where the value (which is a `List<string>`) contains a comma:

```
Dictionary<string, List<String>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<String>>();
dict.Add("STAR-016", new List<string>() { 
    "value a", "value b", "value c", "value 1, value 2, value 3", "value d"
});

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    for (int i = kvp.Value.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        string str = kvp.Value[i];
        if (str.Contains(','))
        {
            var parts = str.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim());
            kvp.Value.RemoveAt(i);
            kvp.Value.InsertRange(i, parts);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/adOERu)

I'm looping from the end to the start to avoid complications because `InsertRange` will add new strings which increases the `Count`.
I'm using `RemoveAt` to replace the strings with commas with new strings(one for each part splitted by comma) which are added. I'm using `InsertRange` instead of `AddRange` because you want to keep the order.

Result:

```
value a
value b
value c
value 1
value 2
value 3
value d
```

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like the OP wants to remove the original CSV.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: But he uses `foreach (var a in ar)
                        {
                            kvp.Value.Add(a);
                        }` to add the parts to the list. Note that i've edited my answer to show how to replace the single element with the splitted elements what seems to be desired.

Comment: Yeah, I agree - the code sample is clearly wrong. I'm basing my comment on the desired output.

Comment: I think you should consider counting down from the end. That way you don't reprocess processed items.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: You're right, "rollbacked" my answer :) I thought it would be unnecessary to loop backwards since i've used  `InsertRange`  instead of `AddRange`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using LINQ:

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "value a",
    "value b",
    "value 1, value 2, value 3",
    "value c"
};

/* THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART: */
/* Replace list with kvp.Value */
list = list.SelectMany( 
         i => i.Split( ',' ).Select( v => v.Trim() ) 
       ).ToList();

foreach ( var item in list )
    Console.WriteLine( item );
```

Output:

> value a
>   value b
>   value 1
>   value 2
>   value 3
>   value c

To use this within your code:

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    if (kvp.Key == "STAR-016")
    {
        var newList = 
            kvp.Value.SelectMany(
                i => i.Split( ',' ).Select( v => v.Trim() )
            );
        kvp.Value.Clear();
        kvp.Value.AddRange(newList);
    }
}
```

*Thanks to @Mudu for pointing out the simpler `i =>` syntax*

Comment: +1 for using LINQ, which is more elegant. However, would `i => i.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim())` not be fine too? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Comment: There's really no point in looping through a `Dictionary` to find a specific key value.  I mean that's what `Dictionary` are literal made for.

Comment: @juharr - You are probably right, but this may be a more complicated loop and we are only seeing a snippet.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: What is `i`? Btw, you cannot assign a value to a `KeyValuePair`, it is read-only.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Lost the `i =>` part in the copy-paste. You are correct about read-only: modified, though your solution has clearly done the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop trough the `List` using `for` instead of `foreach` and modify items

```
for (int i = 0; i < kvp.Value.Count; i++)
{
    if (kvp.Value[i].Contains(','))
        ...
}
```

Comment: I think the loop at issue is not the dictionary loop but the List<string> loop.

Comment: OP wants to replace a single string in each list which contains commas with the strings splitted. So afterwards the list could increase but the original item should be removed.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Using for instead of foreach is the solution, same for dictionary and list.

Comment: @TimSchmelter well, OP had problems modifying collections inside of foreach. You provided OP with full solution, I just showed him the way to do it by himself.

Comment: @VladL: Hmm, this does not even compile since the key is a `string`. The indexer of a dictionary is the lookup to the key, so you could use `dict["STAR-016"]` but not `dict[0]`. A dictionary is not a list.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, I know that dictionary is not a list. I just modified a wrong peace of OP's code. As OP don't have problems with dictionary, my example refers to the list. I've edited my answer, hope it's clear now what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that with one line using `SelectMany`.

```
dict["STAR-016"] = dict["STAR-016"].SelectMany(s=>s.Split(',')).ToList();
```

This replaces the list for your key with one that splits the string on comma, if the string doesn't contain a comma it just returns the string.  You might also consider using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` if you don't want empty strings resulting from consecutive commas.

Comment: +1 for `SelectMany` - I was thinking of Scala's `flatMap` but did not know of `SelectMany` as LINQ's equivalent.

Comment: +1 This is a much simpler syntax if the OP does not need to iterate over the dictionary.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 this can even be used if you loop over the dictionary.  Just replace the 'dict["STAR-016"]` with `kvp.Value`

Comment: @juharr: You might want to consider to use `s.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim())` since the desired result does not contain white-spaces at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 1):

*(edit: juharr's https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875503/17713 does basically the same with build-in LINQ features and in more functional style, which is often more expressive in describing the actual problem)*

I'd go for an approach with `yield` that *does not modify the original collection*. Here is an example code that operates on a `List<string> orig` which may also be in a dictionary:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> orig = new List<string>()
    {
        "value a",
        "value b",
        "value c",
        "value 1, value 2, value 3",
        "value d"
    };

    var result = Flatten(orig).ToList();

    foreach(string s in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Flatten(IList<string> orig)
{
    foreach(string s in orig)
    {
        // split anyway, if there's no colon you just get a one-element
        // array containing s, see
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx
        foreach(string v in s.Split(','))
        {
            yield return v.Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

In a dictionary, you could then replace the result with the original value:

```
dict["STAR-016"] = Flatten(dict["STAR-016"]).ToList()
```

Side note: The above code finds `STAR-016` directly rather than using a `foreach` which is slower. If you did not shorten the code and you're actually just looking up `STAR-016` I'd recommend you to use this way of dictionary lookup.